# Pytest coverage not detect attribut class check

Tags: coverage.py, pytest-cov

Below my class I want to check

```
class Toto:
    me = 0

    def good(self):
       return "OK"
```

With my test launch with `pytest` and `pytest-cov` plugin

```
def test_attr_class():
    assert Toto.me == 0 # True
    assert Toto().good() == "OK"
```

My pytest script is OK but my coverage not detect the attribut me in Toto

[image]

What is wrong ?

Thanks for help

Comment: You haven't shown how you are running coverage, or your tests, so it's impossible to say.

Comment: I use the pytest-cov lib which generate my report after pytest finished

Comment: It would be really useful to have more information.  Likely your class is being imported before coverage is started.  Does this FAQ help?  https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.5.0/faq.html#q-why-do-the-bodies-of-functions-show-as-executed-but-the-def-lines-do-not

Comment: I does not think it is the issue because when I call method it is right, I added more explanation in my post.